# (Done) Reopen the question on finding good candidates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question ([How to find good candidates amid tough competition in the job market?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/112916/3192)) was closed as too broad. However, it asks a single practically answerable question. It has already received a couple of answers and a few comment-answers. In any case, it seems to have only a handful of solutions.

Can we consider it for reopening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casted the final vote, and the post is now open again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's:

- **Too broad**, because it might be seen as asking for a list of things to try (potentially making every one of many answers equally useful). Questions asking for a single thing can also have many valid answers, but usually someone will end up going with only *one* of the answers.
- **Opinion-based**, because the best solution may very well be specific to the industry, region, job, company, competition, candidates and season. That may be too specific (and also not specified in the question) to be answerable using general workplace expertise or experience (apart from giving the general recommendations already included in the question), so answers may come down to little more than throwing stuff against a wall and seeing what sticks.
- **Off-topic**, because it's asking us how to do the job of a recruiter or similar.
- **Unanswerable**, because OP's already tried what we would've recommended. I consider "I want to do A. X, Y and Z didn't or won't work. What else can I try?" to break the Q&A format, because really one should just be asking how to do A, with X, Y, Z and potentially some other solutions being answers (although how to actually *get* said potential solutions as answers to said question is another question altogether).

  The answers so far are mostly non-answers, indirect and/or too obvious, time-consuming or impractical to be useful.